# Android Lollipop EditText: AutoComplete Not Working For Email Addresses

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a bunch of `EditTexts` in a registration Fragment.

On KitKat and below, any `EditText` whose `inputType` is an email address will use the system's autocomplete, which is convenient for users putting in their email addresses.

However, on Lollipop (5.0.1 on a Nexus 4, for what it's worth), it refuses to use autocomplete. Here is my code for setting up the input type:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT));
```

The following code which is just capitalizing the first letter of each word rather than setting the input as an email address **is** causing AutoComplete to work on all API levels (even though the flag I'm setting is for AutoCorrect instead of AutoComplete):

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
```

which is extra-confusing, since looking at the docs for [TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT), it looks like that should actually be *disabling* AutoComplete.

TL;DR: How in the hell do you enable auto-completion on a Lollipop EditText which you're expecting to get an email address?

Answer (score 2):

Nick Butcher has a great [post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/DgLSWqZ7eVj) on this.

Comment: That's definitely helpful if I want to use the account manager for that, but on < Lollipop, this is the pure text editor offering autocorrect suggestions. Is this something that's been disabled in favor of requiring use of the AccountManager in Lollipop?